# Unable to use send keys for disabled Element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

The input field for which I am trying to write the code in selenium:

```
input class="tt-hint" type="text" disabled="" spellcheck="off" autocomplete="off" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);"
```

My code is:

```
WebElementy inp= driver.findElement(By.className("tt-hint"));

inp.sendKeys(new String[] { "mo" });
```

But the above code does not work. The error I keep getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: Element is disabled and so may not be used for actions

Any help is appreciated.

I have modified my code to

> JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
>           js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')",inp);
>
> inp.sendKeys("mo");
>   I get the output as [image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

The exception says it all. The element is not ready to accept any interaction and DISABLED. JavaScript is only option here. I would remove the `disabled` attribute and then use `sendKeys()`

```
String script = "document.getElementsByClassName('tt-hint')[1].removeAttribute('disabled')";
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript(script);

WebElementy inp= driver.findElement(By.className("tt-hint"));
inp.sendKeys("Whatever");
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. In the eclipse that I am using I do not have the option document.getElementsByClassName. What needs to be done?

Comment: That's a javascript and using as string. You do not need have options for them . Just add and execute the test

Comment: When I copy paste it I get the error message as "document.getElementsByClassName(...)[1] is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript` is the only option as said by @Saifur.However you do like this also
Either remove the disabled attribute or go with javascript to set the value itself

```
 WebElement inp = driver.findElement(By.className("tt-hint"));
    //Option 1 remove the disabled attribute
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')",inp);
    inp.sendKeys("val");

    //Option 2 go for javascript set value
     js.executeScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]",inp,"val");
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried using the above code. Once the user inputs the keys the input box has to suggest the relevant searches as per the key entered by the user, just like google-the auto complete feature. It's not working.

Comment: what's the website you are testing and whcih part is not working

Comment: I have edited the question, please check. I have attached the image.

Comment: @Keerti i guess you are doing this in a wrong way.Can you provide the link to the webpage you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the code for Selenium C#, for a hidden Textbox/TextArea

```
IWebElement element;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value=arguments[1]", element, inputValueYouWantToPlace);
```

Some controls won't recognize the given text and gives error like 'please provide input value'- in this case Enable the element just before sending the value using SendKeys()
`

```
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", input);
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
element.SendKeys(inputValueYouWantToPlace);
```

`